# HP openview servicedesk: looking for api information ?

Tags: code-quality, api, information

Good day folks.

I am very confused in this situation. I need to implement system which will be based on [HP open view service desk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_OpenView) 4.5 api. But this system are reached the end of supporting period. On oficial site no information available
**I am looking an information about this API(articles, samples etc)**. Now i have only web-api.jar and javadoc. Methods in javadoc is bad documented.

If you have any info, please share it with me. Thanks.

**Second question: there are methods for api(with huge amount of methods) understanding if it not documented or information is not available?**

PS:If it question is not belong here i will delete it.

Comment: Do you have an HP Passport?  If you do, try this: https://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/document/KM16823/binary/ovou8x_APIDeveloperReference_Ed7_pdf?searchIdentifier=-1d9875b3%3a12b3720d9d4%3a-7c3e&resultType=document.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an HP passport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a blog post http://tebest.net/hp-openview-servicedesk-api/50 that came up as the first search result on Google, the second search result was this question. You could probably contact the person who wrote the blog entry to understand more about the API.

I am writing this as an answer because I am not able to comment on the question.

Comment: I send email to this person few weeks ago, but not received any answers yet.

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry Dmitry Just wondering if you have tried the HP forums (http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/HP-Service-Desk-Support-and-News/bd-p/itrc-160#.T_E0IJFhiAU) to get help? I am pretty sure **those HP guys** would not be hanging around on SE.

Comment: thank you. I read offcial hp forums, but i thought official hp guys, read SE.

Comment: i will write to forum.